# why bootstrap 5.2.2 min.js cannot handle dropdown sub menu

Tags: bootstrap-5

i get problem when i use

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this version cannot make toggle class dropdown . here is sub menu dropdown

```
 <li>
                   <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                   <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                       <li>
                           <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
```

when i use 4.2.1 this sub menu dropdown work.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

why 5.2.2 cannot make sub menu dropdown

Comment: Did you check the documentation if the syntax between version 4 and 5 is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `data-toggle="collapse"` but in Bootstrap v5, it is now `data-bs-toggle="collapse"`.

It is mentioned in [Bootstrap migration guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#javascript).